# How do I get powershell run from a scheduled tasks to pick up the newest environment variables

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have a scheduled task that runs a powershell script as the system user. That's all good, except from the part that it doesn't pick up the latest environment variables as it seem.

I have verified that the environment variable in question is a "System Variable" and not just a user variable for me only.

In the scheduled tasks I've specified PowerShell as the command and the provided arguments like:

```
-command "& 'myscript' 'my args'"
```

The script runs, but I fail to import a module since it seems like the scheduled task is using an old environment.

The "Local Service" user can see the updated variables, but not the system user.

Answer (score 0):

how do you set your environment variable ?using setx ?
you can use the following to interactively verify the variable :
From a elevated command prompt I used `setx / m test testvalue`
Then I used psexec to run a powershell as the system user :
`psexec -i -s powershell.exe -noexit`
In the opened powershell, I can read the variable :

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $env:test
testvalue
```

---

**Update**
I confirm the newest environment variables are not seen from the scheduler. But after a reboot, this is working.
[A post on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/527727/107325) suggest that killing all `taskeng.exe` should be enough but this has not work on my 2008R2 server.

My guess is the registry values are read when the schedule service start and not reloaded at each task run. Still it does not explain why the variables are accessible to the local service account ...

As a workaround you should be able to read the env. value directly from the registry

Comment: The env variables were set when I installed pscx. Does it make a big difference in how the variables where set if I can verify they are in the list of system variables?

Comment: I did verify that I get the environment variables when running powershell as system using psexec. But still no look when it runs as a scheduled task.

Comment: your problem is that you cant use pscx from system user right ? I've this module installed under my user account, but when i use `get-module -listAvailable` from the system account pscx is not found. I guess you will have to install pscx from the system account. Or maybe ask @KeithHill who participated to that project

Comment: when I run with `psexec -i -s...` I can see the module since it is installed and added to the `psmodulepath`. The problem only occurs when running the scheduled task.

Comment: sorry, I have no more idea

Comment: thanks anyway. Got one upvote for trying :). It is really weird error though.

Comment: Yep. cant you pass the env variable as a parameter for your powershell script ? this work from the run menu : `powershell.exe -noexit -command "& c:\temp\test.ps1" %temp%`

Comment: I could do that, but that seems like a hacky way to do it. I can't see a reason why the system user doesn't pick up the environment variables. The Local Service user does pick up the variables.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59999/discussion-between-kayasax-and-tomas-jansson).